# injection page in iframe cause js error

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, header, abbyy

I have an iframe and i try to add it header, with ajax, but it does'nt work. A js method in page we try to put in iframe cause an issue :

method not defined and cause a blank page. The page we try to include is asp.net (flexicapture from abbyy)

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET", 
 url: "http://172.20.30.8/FlexiCapture12",
contentType: "application/json",
beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
        xhr.setRequestHeader("some_custom_header", "foo");},
success: function(data){
console.log(data);
    $("#myFrame").attr('src',"data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(data));
}
});
```

any idea ?

here the error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Ui_Model is not defined

with simple tag iframe, it works but we need to inject header or cookie into

PS: this is the content iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>UI</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" 
href="/FlexiCapture12/Login/Content/images/TabIcon.ico" />
    <link href="/FlexiCapture12/Login/WebCommon/WebCommonCss? 
 v=QrXq6ljGiWHstlXVpAXLMNzZ6cyaoydsT5gsI629ER01" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/FlexiCapture12/Login/Content/css? 
 v=CcVW8jp8169r4jTB7Wkw2N1TrY1RMIrcOXVeOL3LaMo1" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/FlexiCapture12/Login/Content/general/css? 
v=I0nviCV6U1d3tl9uZqDz0tVCXIeZOrYHEACjHLKxhVA1" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <script src="/FlexiCapture12/Login/WebCommonExternal? 
 v=hK5886_opsMQ3AxjzkVhwRtKuughLHC1pqmGAGdDaZw1"></script>

     <script src="/FlexiCapture12/Login/WebCommon?v=yfkjMl06jF6DhlPjz- 
 6CxMqczHjqZIjKpnCyLxwAy8s1"></script>


<script src="/FlexiCapture12/Login/bundles/modernizr? 
 v=inCVuEFe6J4Q07A0AcRsbJic_UE5MwpRMNGcOtk94TE1"></script>

<script src="/FlexiCapture12/Login/bundles/signaljs?v="></script>

<script src="/FlexiCapture12/Login/bundles/moment? 
v=2v8Tw1bW5jhBpfywRx36sJR1xZCerziad7XUy33UKio1"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="/FlexiCapture12/Login/Content/JsEnvironment"></script>

<script src="/FlexiCapture12/Login/bundles/standart? 
 v=m5NAFE0GQZHGrd4XGUYauBkrXpxuQbhKpEOsnNk2C8k1"></script>



    <script 

type="text/javascript">Ui_Model({"PageId":"Login","InstallationLanguage":"en- 
 US","SupportedLanguages":[{"FineObjectsCode":0,"Id":"en-US","Name":"English 
(United States)"},{"FineObjectsCode":-1,"Id":"en-GB","Name":"English (United 
Kingdom)"},{"FineObjectsCode":1,"Id":"ru","Name":"Русский"}, 
 {"FineObjectsCode":2,"Id":"de","Name":"Deutsch"}, 
 {"FineObjectsCode":3,"Id":"fr","Name":"Français"}, 
 {"FineObjectsCode":5,"Id":"es","Name":"Español"}, 
 {"FineObjectsCode":26,"Id":"ja","Name":"日本
```

"}],"CurrentUserInfo":null,"PermissionRequests":null,"UserPermissions":0,"Avai 
   libleStations":null,"NoDatabase":false,"DoTenantsExist":false});

Comment: Which part of the code gives `Uncaught ReferenceError`?

Comment: the iframe content

Comment: the method is in the script imported above : <script src="/FlexiCapture12/Login/bundles/standart?v=m5NAFE0GQZHGrd4XGUYauBkrXpxuQbhKpEOsnNk2C8k1"></script>